# Deadlock with async Task.Run method with Wait from synchronous method and timeout

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, async-await, deadlock

I have a method defined as:

```
public Task<ReturnsMessage> Function()
{
    var task = Task.Run(() =>
    {
         var result = SyncMethod();
         return new ReturnMessage(result);
    });
    
    if (task.Wait(delay))
    {
        return task;
    }

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<ReturnMessage>();
    tcs.SetCanceled();
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Now it is called in a loop based on maxAttempts value:

(method name RetryableInvoke)

```
for (var i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++)
{
    try
    {
        return Function().Result;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
}
```

It works perfectly fine, however when there is a massive load I am finding that the threads are increasing drastically and dump is showing me this warnings:

[image]
Can anyone suggest me the best possible way to handle this situation, so that I don't see any kind of deadlocks?

Comment: The best way? Use Task based methods all the way of so you do not have to block using .Wait or . Result

Comment: Thanks @PeterBons The reason I am creating task because I want to timeout my call to the downstream system and the only way that I know is either I use cancellation token or Wait(withDelay). Even if I don't use Wait I will have to use .Result because response will come back to sync method (without async).

Comment: @codebased When using async then do it async **all the way** - period

Comment: @codebased BTW your `Function` method is a mix of nearly all "Don't do an async" advices. It seems to be async but it is totally sync. Why do you return a task at all?

Comment: What is inside syncmethod?

Comment: @PeterBons syncmethod contains a call to another system that I don’t control and it is a socket sync connection

Comment: You are using the term [deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock) incorrectly. This term means that a program is in a complete halt, because two or more execution flows are waiting each other. This is not the behavior that you are observing. What you observe is delays, temporary freezes, irresponsiveness etc. Your program completes all the work that is starting, just not fast and smoothly enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not deadlocking the application. While `Task.Run` would execute the delegate on a background thread, the following call of `Task.Wait` effectively converts the originally concurrent `Task.Run` code back to synchronous code: `Task.Wait` and `Task.Result` *synchronously* wait for the `Task` to complete.

What you assume to be a deadlock is rather the result of a frozen main thread, caused by synchronously waiting for a long-running operation to complete.
Below the provided solutions is a section that briefly explains how `Task.Result`, `Task.Wait` and `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` can create a real deadlock.

Although the `Task` related deadlock and your frozen main thread have different causes, the solution to both is similar: convert the synchronous code to an asynchronous version by introducing `async/await`. This will keep the main thread responsive.

Using `async/await` will replace the synchronous `Task.Wait` and also make `Task.Result` redundant.

The following two examples show how to convert your synchronous version to asynchronous code and provide two solutions to implement a timeout for a `Task`: the first and not recommended solution uses `Task.WhenAny` together with cancellation.
The second and recommended solution uses the timeout feature of the `CancellationTokenSource`.

It is generally recommended to check the class API for asynchronous versions instead of using `Task.Run`. In case your 3rd party library exposes an asynchronous API you should use this to replace the `Task.Run`. This is because true asynchronous implementations access the kernel to use the system's hardware to execute code asynchronously without the need to create background threads.

### Timeout implementation using [`Task.WhenAny`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenany?view=netframework-4.8) (not recommended)

This example uses the characteristic of `Task.WhenAny` which awaits a set of `Task` objects and returns the one that completes first and we usually cancel the remaining ones.
When creating a timed `Task` for example by using `Task.Delay` and pass it along with other `Task` objects to `Task.WhenAny`, we can create a race: if the timed task completes first, we can cancel the remaining `Task` objects.

```cs
public async Task<ReturnMessage> FunctionAsync()
{
  using var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  {
    // Create the Task with cancellation support
    var task = Task.Run(
      () =>
      {
        // Check if the task needs to be cancelled
        // because the timeout task ran to completion first
        cancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

        // It is recommended to pass a CancellationToken to the
        // SyncMethod() too to allow more fine grained cancellation
        var result = SyncMethod(cancellationTokenSource.Token);
        return new ReturnMessage(result);
      }, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);

    // Create a timeout Task with cancellation support
    var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
    Task firstCompletedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask);

    // Cancel the remaining Task that has lost the race.
    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

    if (firstCompletedTask == timeoutTask)
    {
      // The 'timoutTask' has won the race and has completed before the delay. 
      // Return an empty result.
      // Because the cancellation was triggered inside this class,
      // we can avoid to re-throw the OperationCanceledException
      // and return an error/empty result.
      return new ReturnMessage(null);
    }

    // The 'task' has won the race, therefore
    // return its result
    return await task;
  }
}
```

### Timeout implementation using the [`CancellationTokenSouce`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=netframework-4.8) constructor overload (recommended)

This example uses a specific constructor overload that accepts a `TimeSpan` to configure a timeout. When the defined timeout has expired the `CancellationTokeSource` will automatically cancel itself.

```
public async Task<ReturnsMessage> FunctionAsync()
{
  var timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500);
  using (var timeoutCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout))
  {
    try
    {
      return await Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
          // Check if the timeout has elapsed
          timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

          // Allow every called method to invoke the cancellation
          var result = SyncMethod(timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token);
          return new ReturnMessage(result);
        }, timeoutCancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {          
      // Return an empty result.
      // Because the cancellation was triggered inside this class,
      // we can avoid to re-throw the OperationCanceledException
      // and return an error/empty result.
      return new ReturnMessage(null);
    }
  }
}
```

To complete both of the above examples that converted the originally synchronous code (`Function()` to asynchronous code (`FunctionAsync()`), we have to `await` the new method properly:

```cs
// The caller of this new asynchronous version must be await this method too.
// `await` must be used  up the call tree whenever a method defined as `async`. 
public async Task<ReturnMessage> void RetryableInvokeAsync()
{ 
  ReturnMessage message = null;
  for (var i = 0; i < maxAttempts; i++)
  {
    message = await FunctionAsync();

    // Never use exceptions to control the flow.
    // Control the for-loop using a condition based on the result.
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(message.Text))
    {
      break;
    }
  }

  return message;
}
```

---

### Why `Task.Result`, `Task.Wait` and `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` create a deadlock when used with `async` code

First, because a method is defined using the `async` key word it supports asynchronous execution of operations with the help of the `await` operator. Common types that support `await` are `Task`, `Task<TResult>`, `ValueTask`, `ValueTask<TResult>` or any object that matches the criteria of an [awaitable expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11882-awaitable-expressions).

Inside the `async` method the `await` captures the `SynchronizationContext` of the calling thread, the thread it is executed on. `await` will also create a callback for the code that follows the `await` statement, called "continuation".

This callback is enqueued on the captured `SynchronizationContext` (by using `SynchronizationContext.Post`) and executed once the awaitable (e.g., `Task`) has signalled its completion.

Now that the callback is enqueued (stored) for later execution, `await` allows the current thread to continue to do work asynchronously while executing the awaitable.

`async/await` basically instructs the compiler to create a [state machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/task-asynchronous-programming-model#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod).

Given is the following example that produces three potential deadlocks:

```cs
public void RetryableInvoke()
{ 
  // Potential deadlock #1.
  // Result forces the asynchronous method to be executed synchronously.
  string textMessage = FunctionAsync().Result;

  // Potential deadlock #2.
  // Wait forces the asynchronous method to be executed synchronously.
  // The caller is literally waiting for the Task to return.
  textMessage = FunctionAsync().Wait();

  // Potential deadlock #3.
  // Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult() forces the asynchronous method to be executed synchronously.
  // The caller is literally waiting for the Task to return.
  textMessage = FunctionAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

private async Task<string> FunctionAsync() 
{
  // Capture the SynchronizationContext of the caller's thread by awaiting the Task.
  // Because the calling thread synchronously waits, the callers context is not available to process the continuation callback.
  // This means that the awaited Task can't complete and return to the captured context ==> deadlock
  string someText = await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
      /* Background thread context */

      return "A message";
    });

  /* 
     Code after the await is the continuation context 
     and is executed on the captured SynchronizationContext of the 
     thread that called FunctionAsync. 
     
     In case ConfigureAwait is explicitly set to false, 
     the continuation is the same as the context of the background thread.
   */

  // The following lines can only be executed 
  // after the awaited Task has successfully returned (to the captured SynchronizationContext)
  someText += " More text";
  return someText;
}
```

In the above example `Task.Run` executes the delegate on a new `ThreadPool` thread. Because of the `await` the caller thread can continue to execute other operations instead of just waiting.

Once the `Task` has signaled its completed, the pending enqueued continuation callback is ready for execution on the captured `SynchronizationContext`.
This requires the caller thread to stop its current work to finish the remaining code that comes after the `await` statement by executing the continuation callback.

The above example breaks the asynchronous concept by using `Task.Wait`, `Task.Result` and `Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. This `Task` members will *synchronously* wait and therefore effectively cause the `Task` to execute *synchronously*, which means:

a) The caller thread will block itself (wait) until the `Task` is completed. Because the thread is now *synchronously waiting* it is not able to do anything else. If instead the invocation had been *asynchronously* using `async/await`, then instead of waiting, the parent thread will continue to execute other operations (e.g., UI related operations in case of a UI thread) until the `Task` signals its completion.
Because of the synchronous waiting the caller thread can't execute the pending continuation callback.

b) The `Task` signals completion but can't return until the continuation callback has executed. The remaining code (the code after `Task.Wait`) is supposed to be executed on captured `SynchronizationContext`, which is the caller thread.
Since the caller thread is still synchronously waiting for the `Task` to return, it can't execute the pending continuation callback.
Now the `Task` must wait for the caller thread to be ready/responsive (finished with the synchronous waiting) to execute the continuation.

*a)* and *b)* describe the mutual exclusive situation that finally locks both the caller and the thread pool thread: the caller thread is waiting for the `Task`, and the `Task` is waiting for the caller thread. Both wait for each other indefinitely. This is the deadlock. If the caller thread is the main thread then the complete application is deadlocked and hangs.

Because the example used `Task.Wait` in one place and `Task.Result` in another, it has created two potential deadlock situations:

From [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.8#remarks):

> Accessing the property's [`Task.Result`] get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; **it is equivalent to calling the Wait method**.

`Task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` creates the third potential deadlock.

### How to fix the deadlock

To fix the deadlock we can use `async/await` (recommend) or `ConfigreAwait(false)`.

`ConfigreAwait(true)` is the implicit default: the continuation callback is always executed on the captured `SynchronizationConext`.

`ConfigreAwait(false)` instructs `await` (the state machine) to execute the continuation callback on the current thread pool thread of the awaited `Task`. It configures `await` to ignore the captured `SynchronizationContext`.

`ConfigreAwait(false)` basically wraps the original `Task` to create a replacement `Task` that causes `await` to not enqueue the continuation callback on the captured `SyncronizationContext`.

It's recommended to always use `ConfigreAwait(false)` where executing the callback on the caller thread is not required (this is the case for library code or non UI code in general). This is because `ConfigreAwait(false)` improves the performance of your code as it avoids the overhead introduced by registering the callback.
`ConfigreAwait(false)` should be used on the complete call tree (on every `await` not only the first).

Note, there are exceptions where the callback still executes on the caller's `SynchronizationContext`, for example when awaiting an already completed `Task`.

```cs
public async Task RetryableInvokeAsync()
{ 
  // Awaiting the Task always guarantees the caller thread to remain responsive. 
  // It can temporarily leave the context and will therefore not block it.
  string textMessage = await FunctionAsync();

  // **Only** if the awaited Task was configured 
  // to not execute the continuation on the caller's SnchronizationContext
  // by using ConfigureAwait(false), the caller can use 
  // Wait(), GetAwaiter().GetResult() or access the Result property 
  // without creating a deadlock
  string textMessage = FunctionAsync.Result;
}

private async Task<string> FunctionAsync() 
{
  // Because the awaited Task is configured to not use the caller's SynchronizationContext by using ConfigureAwait(false), 
  // the Task don't need to return to the captured context 
  // ==> no deadlock potential
  string someText = await Task.Run(
    () =>
    {
      /* Background thread context */

      return "A message";
    }).ConfigureAwait(false);

  /* 
     Code after the await is the continuation context 
     and is not executed on the captured SynchronizationContext.

     Because ConfigureAwait is explicitly set to false, 
     the continuation is the same as the context of the background thread.
    
     Additionally, ConfigureAwait(false) has improved the performance 
     of the async code. 
  */

  // The following lines will always execute
  // after the awaited Task has ran to completion
  someText += " More text";
  return someText;
}
```

Comment: fmi: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: Such a great and in-depth explanation, and then you got only 6 upvotes, shame :) Nice work

Answer (score 0):

You are starting tasks with Task.Run, then you are returning cancelled if they timeout, but you never stop the tasks. They just continue to run in the background.

Your code should be async/await and use CancellationSource and handle the cancellation token inside the SyncMethod(). But if you can't and you want, as I understand it, to run a method asynchronously and kill it forcefully after a while, you should probably use Threads and Abort them.

Warning: aborting threads is not safe unless you know what you are doing and it might even be removed from .NET in future versions.

I've actually researched this a while ago: https://siderite.dev/blog/how-to-timeout-task-and-make-sure-it.html